# How do make a simple bot that auto reacts to every message in channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this code, in cog, it doesn't do anything and I dont have any errors,
discord.py.
I want the bot to auto react on every message in specific channel

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*')

class Autoreact(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):

        self.client = client
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if (message.channel.id == "817770701603340289"):
            
            await message.add_reaction(":daek:817793235988643861")



def setup(client):

    client.add_cog(Autoreact(client))```
````

Answer (score 3):

ID's are integers, not strings

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.channel.id == 817770701603340289:            
        await message.add_reaction(":daek:817793235988643861")
```